# Correct way to get a count of matching elements in Nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to test if a todo app has the right number of elements.

The docs seem to deal almost exclusively with single elements, so I had to use the Selenium Protocol functions. Would this be the right way to test the count of matching selectors (in this case, checking for 2 li elements)?

```
client.elements('css selector','#todo-list li', function (result) {
    client.assert.equal(result.value.length, 2);
});
```

This works in my test, but I wasn't sure if there were gotchas around using a callback for this. Also not sure why Nightwatch doesn't have any helper functions dealing with more than one element.

Comment: Seems to me it's the proper way to use Selenium Protocol with Nightwatch (see http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements). Why do you doubt the callback? I agree it's not pretty, but it works like it should

Comment: I see the following when I console.log(result) : { state: 'success',
  sessionId: '4568bfcf-fa1a-4d4c-bd19-082c3983cc42',
  hCode: 1527071402,
  value: [],
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 } --- The element is not passed into the function. Any ideas?

Comment: I was using 'id' instead of 'css selector.' Using 'css selector' does produce a length.

Answer (score 13):

I found the following very elegant solution within a VueJS template.  It shows how to add a [custom assertion](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-assertions) into Nightwatch that counts the number of elements returned by a selector.  See http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-assertions for details of how to write custom assertions within Nightwatch.

Once installed, usage is as simple as:

```
browser.assert.elementCount('#todo-list li', 2)
```

The plugin:

```
// A custom Nightwatch assertion.
// the name of the method is the filename.
// can be used in tests like this:
//
//   browser.assert.elementCount(selector, count)
//
// for how to write custom assertions see
// http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-assertions
exports.assertion = function (selector, count) {
  this.message = 'Testing if element <' + selector + '> has count: ' + count;
  this.expected = count;
  this.pass = function (val) {
    return val === this.expected;
  }
  this.value = function (res) {
    return res.value;
  }
  this.command = function (cb) {
    var self = this;
    return this.api.execute(function (selector) {
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
    }, [selector], function (res) {
      cb.call(self, res);
    });
  }
}
```

This code was added to [vuejs-templates by yyx990803](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/3fc5eb210f6376fe7ca2eb27a6eb606216c214fe/template/test/e2e/custom-assertions/elementCount.js) in 2016. So full credit goes to [yyx990803](https://github.com/yyx990803).

Comment: Any chance you tell us how to implement this as well? By that I mean setup nightwatch to take this custom assertion

Comment: To add this:  Create a directory called plugins or whatever. In your nightwatch.json file add that directory path to  'custom_assertions_path'. Add the code in a file called elementCount.js and add the file to your plugin directory and that should work.

Comment: I've added a TypeScript version that does this without having to execute code in the browser.

Answer (score 8):

Just to reassure you I do a similar thing when trying to grab all matching elements, ex:

```
    browser.elements("xpath","//ul[@name='timesList']/h6", function(result){
        els = result.value;
        var i = 0;
        els.forEach(function(el, j, elz){
            browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(text) {
                dates[i] = text.value;
                i++;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Important to notice CSS selector is **browser.elements('css selector', ...)** but the XPath selector is **browser.elements('xpath', ...)**. I have been a while trying to work with 'xpath selector' and no... that's not the name selector.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, if you want to be sure that `n` number of elements exist, you can use a combination of `:nth-of-type`/`:nth-child` selectors and nightwatch's `expect`.

For example, if you want to test if `#foo` has nine direct children:

```js
function(browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://example.com')
    .expect.element('#foo > *:nth-child(9)').to.be.present;
  browser.end();
}
```

Or if `#bar` has three direct `article` children:

```js
function(browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://example.com')
    .expect.element('#bar > article:nth-of-type(3)').to.be.present;
  browser.end();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution seems to only work if the target elements are 'cleanly' organized.  For example I have a shopping cart  of `div.items div.item` with three items in the cart (`div.item`).  Unfortunately there is also a hidden `div.empty` for when there are no contents in the cart that is located as a sibling to the `div.item` elements.  So in this scenario, when attempting to count the `div.item` elements, it is actually `:nth-of-type(2-4)` since the empty div element is the first child of the item element's parent.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [expect.elements(`<selector>`).count()](https://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-elements-count):

```
  browser.expect.elements('div').count.to.equal(10);
  browser.expect.elements('p').count.to.not.equal(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I adapted [Chris K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45688465/894361) to support XPath expressions by using the built-in method `this.api.elements`:

```
exports.assertion = function elementCount(selector, count) {
  this.message = 'Testing if element <' + selector + '> has count: ' + count

  this.expected = count

  this.pass = function pass(val) {
    return val === this.expected
  }

  this.value = function value(res) {
    return res.value.length
  }

  this.command = function command(callback) {
    return this.api.elements(this.client.locateStrategy, selector, callback)
  }
}
```

For usage instructions and credits see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45688465/894361)

Answer (score 0):

And if you like a bit of TypeScript, here is an assertion that will confirm the element count:

```js
import { NightwatchCallbackResult, NightwatchAssertion, NightwatchAPI } from "nightwatch";

module.exports.assertion = function (selector: string, count: number, description?: string) {

    this.message = description || `Testing if element <${selector}> has count: ${count}`;
    this.expected = count;

    this.pass = (value: number) => value === this.expected;

    this.value = (result: number) => result;

    this.command = (callback: (result: number) => void): NightwatchAPI => {

        const self: NightwatchAssertion = this;

        return self.api.elements(this.client.locateStrategy, selector, (result: NightwatchCallbackResult) => {
            callback(result.value.length);
        });
    }

}
```

Use like this:

```js
browser.assert.elementCount('body', 1, 'There is only one body element');
```